# Why Rx is freezing when I call Last() in OnCompleted delegate?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm learning Rx and I don't understand why my code is suspending. This is easy Rx observable and I want to provide last element when it is completed.

```
var observable = Observable.Range(1, 20);
var results = new List<int>();
int lastElement = 0;

observable.Subscribe(results.Add, () =>
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Completed " + results.Count);
    lastElement = observable.Last(); // *it is suspeneded here
});

// lastElement = observable.Last(); // **here it works
Assert.AreEqual(results.Last(), lastElement);
```

We have all code in same thread and results collection is filled. 
If you uncomment lastElement assigning after subscribe method and comment calling observable.Last() it works as expected. Can somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 2):

The call to `Last` is a *blocking call* that returns the final element in an Rx stream. In order to determine the final element, at least one `OnNext` followed by an `OnCompleted` must be sent.

#### Edit

Enigmativity makes an important correction in the comments and I'm adjusting my answer accordingly. The following code will not block:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = Observable.Range(0, 10, NewThreadScheduler.Default);
    source.Subscribe(o => {
        Console.WriteLine(source.Last());
    });
}
```

In this code, because we specified `NewThreadScheduler.Default`, each subscription will run on it's own thread.

It's important to keep in mind that there are two entirely separate subscriptions to the `Range` operator here. One for `Last` and one for the anonymous observer created in the Subscribe call. I'll call that one X.

`Last` needs to see all the events from the source to determine which is the final event ("last" is not the most recent event, it's the final event). When `Last` is hit, it's subscription will run through to completion. At this point, the first invocation of X's OnNext handler will resume. The second iteration of X's handler will cause *another* subscription to the source due to `Last`.

By the end of the run, there will have been 11 subscriptions made to the source. Not very efficient!

In the code in the question, because the default scheduler of `Range` is `Scheduler.CurrentThread`, *all events across all subscriptions run on the **same** thread*.

Now `Last` cannot complete. It's subscription can't run because it's events will be scheduled to run on the very same thread the `OnNext` handler of X is already running on. You have a deadlock.

This is a good example of the danger of mixing synchronous and asynchronous code.

Comment: I don't think that your reasoning is correct. Unless you specify a scheduler, the `Range` operator produces values using `Scheduler.CurrentThread`. So, as a result of the Rx guarantee that `OnNext` calls don't overlap the `.Last()` call inside the `Subscribe` blocks because it is waiting for the `OnNext` to complete before releasing a value.

Comment: Nice spot!! I don't even think you need to consider the non-overlapping guarantee because that only applies within the context of a single subscription. It's simply because they are both observing on the same thread.